Formula Salesforce all Dates in one Filter
I am building a CRM report with customer engagement from business communications.
In the report, for each mailing, I will group data such as Open, Click, etc, which are obtained by counting dedicated checkboxes for each activity.
Before I come up with the question I need to explain the structure of my data: each record row is composed of a lookup towards the contact, checkboxes demonstrating or not any actions, and for each of these the date when the action took place.
Based on this, I need all of these actions to be filtered for a single date, and not filtered according to each of them.
An example follows:
Starting Situation:
1 record row:Contact; Send ---> True(2024-01-01);      Open---> True(2024-01-02)   ;Click---> True(2024-01-02)
  Send                    Click                Open

     1                      1                     1

After Adding a filter from (2024-01-01)  to (2024-01-01):
    Send                    Click                Open

      1                      1                     0
                              

Do you know of any solution to remedy my problem or should I reciprocate the data structure and possibly create a row for each interaction although it is from the same contact?
Thank you

The data model should be one to many where parent is Contact and children are Interactions. Each Interaction = status, timestamp.
